# Remove empty space from seaborn boxplot

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, seaborn

I made a seaborn boxplot but it contains an empty space on the left side of the plot

```
print(rain_df)
```

```
            date  rain_gauge_value_24hr
96    2017-01-11                    9.0
120   2017-01-12                    5.3
144   2017-01-13                    5.7
240   2017-01-17                    1.0
288   2017-01-19                    7.0
...          ...                    ...
37920 2021-05-06                    4.0
38064 2021-05-12                    1.8
38088 2021-05-13                    0.2
38184 2021-05-17                    2.0
38352 2021-05-24                    0.2
```

```
rain_month = rain_df[['date','rain_gauge_value_24hr']]

rain_month['month'] = pd.Categorical.from_codes(rain_month['date'].dt.month,categories=list(calendar.month_name),ordered=True)

rain_month = rain_month.melt(id_vars ='month', value_vars=['rain_gauge_value_24hr'], value_name='rain_gauge_value_24hr')

print(rain_month)
```

```
       month               variable  rain_gauge_value_24hr
0    January  rain_gauge_value_24hr                    9.0
1    January  rain_gauge_value_24hr                    5.3
2    January  rain_gauge_value_24hr                    5.7
3    January  rain_gauge_value_24hr                    1.0
4    January  rain_gauge_value_24hr                    7.0
..       ...                    ...                    ...
836      May  rain_gauge_value_24hr                    4.0
837      May  rain_gauge_value_24hr                    1.8
838      May  rain_gauge_value_24hr                    0.2
839      May  rain_gauge_value_24hr                    2.0
840      May  rain_gauge_value_24hr                    0.2
```

```
ax=sn.boxplot(x='month', y='rain_gauge_value_24hr', hue='variable', data=rain_month, palette="Set3", linewidth=1)

ax.set_title('Joliette')
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
ax.set_yscale('log')

ax.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))
```

[image]

What's causing that empty spot on the plot? How can I fix this? Is there a better approach to making this plot?

EDIT:

```
rain_month['month'].value_counts(dropna=False)
```

```
January      102
February      99
March         80
April         78
December      71
November      67
May           66
July          63
August        62
June          56
October       55
September     42
               0
Name: month, dtype: int64
```

Hmm, thats strange.

Comment: A better option than the accepted answer is to clean the month column by removing values that don't correspond to an actual month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change the x-axis limits with [set_xlim](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xlim.html)

```
ax.set_xlim(xmin=0.5)
```

Comment: That fixed it, but can you explain why this occured?

Comment: Well, I didn't look in detail *why* this happened, but you obviously have an empty group (could be NaN for instance) with 0 values. Seaborn uses index from 0 for the ticks. So, the first (empty) box spans -0.5/0.5

Answer (score 2):

Python documentation for [`calendar.month_name`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html#calendar.month_name) says this:

> An array that represents the months of the year in the current locale. This follows normal convention of January being month number 1, so it has a length of 13 and `month_name[0]` is the empty string.

```py
>>> import calendar
... calendar.month_name[:4]
['', 'January', 'February', 'March']
```

You see the first empty string as the first month tick on X axis. You can get rid of it like this:

```py
rain_month['month'] = pd.Categorical.from_codes(
    rain_month['date'].dt.month - 1, 
    calendar.month_name[1:],
    ordered=True,
)
```